# Would this question asking for an equation or formula be on topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I posted [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68950/how-to-calculate-the-probability-of-the-outcome-of-a-vampire-the-masqurade-roll) on another stack.  The question is on-topic there, however it is not getting a lot of traction.  More to the point, I am asking for an equation or formula, and they are giving me [AnyDice](http://anydice.com/)‡ scripts.

- I understand I will need to edit in a *lot* more context (there are assumptions made in the language of that post that would not apply here.)
- I *barely* passed high school stats... 10 years ago.

Would that question be considered on topic here?  Even if on topic, and presuming I edited in the correct level of context, would that be a *good question* for here?

‡ A site which outputs the probability of some types of dice rolls.  Neat, but not what I need.

Comment: On topic if phrased suitably for our site: See questions like [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102962/dice-probability-amount-of-hits-in-a-pool), [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24385/distribution-of-complex-results-for-pool-of-ten-sided-dice-specific-to-custom-t), [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32309/relevancy-of-order-statistics-to-the-roll-and-keep-dice-mechanic), [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110671/probability-for-completely-unfair-stats-when-rolling-ability-scores-using-4d6-dr), ....

Comment: ... [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116792/dungeons-dragons-attack-hit-probability-success-percentage) and so forth. Just be sure to explain the mechanic clearly, try to avoid RPG jargon and define any that you do use. [The question you posted there would barely need to change here. If you want to request migration you could, or alternatively you could make a (somewhat differently phrased) new post here.]

Comment: gung ... if you see this, do you see the comment by the mod at the bottom of the linked question? It relates to our earlier conversation about some SE sites being a lot more proactive about removing comments. Similar comments can be seen on many posts there.

Comment: @Glen_b http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174099/how-to-calculate-the-probability-of-the-outcome-of-this-convoluted-dice-rolling is this sufficiently edited?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes; it would be on-topic on this site, but the question's context needs to be clearly explained, as the folks here might not understand role-playing game terms like "vampire", etc.

However, I see that these terms do not get in the way of the question or in any way make it difficult to understand. So, you can omit those terms and ask the question as a pure statistical dice probability question.

And yes, [dice](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dice) questions are very well on-topic here.